# error on create a virtual machine with scotch.io on mac

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to create a virtual machine with scotch.io but i get this error when i try vagrant up

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
        for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade both VirtualBox and Vagrant to the latest versions to make it work.